# content provider

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

i had created class that extends contentprovider.
I had override the 6 functions

```
@override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialvalues) {

    ContentValues values;
    if(initialvalues != null){
        values = new ContentValues(initialvalues);
    }else{
        values = new ContentValues();
    }
    SQLiteDatabase mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long rowId = mDb.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_PROGRAM, null, values);
    if(rowId > 0){
        Uri programUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(null, rowId);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(programUri, null);
        return programUri;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
}

private void createdata(){
    String a = "a", b = "b", c = "c", d= "d";
    //how i going to call the content provider to let me to add in data?
}
```

my question is how to call the insert() to add data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtain ContentResolver instance via getContentResolver() [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#insert%28android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) method.

**UPDATE** [That's the best tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)